# How to make a MdiClient background transparent?

Tags: winforms, mdi

I tried

```
MdiClientObject.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

but got this error message "Control does not support transparent background colors."? Does anyone know how to make the background transparent?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have layered child windows.